# Leaflet Add Marker on click with pop up of lat lng coordinates?

Tags: leaflet

I would like the ability to click on my map and have the following happen:

- Add a temporary marker to the map that will display the lat lng coordinates of that marker.

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet-src.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-extra-markers@1.0.6/src/assets/js/leaflet.extra-markers.min.js"></script>

<body>
...
<div id="carteDiv"> </div>
</body>

<script>
// Map object
var m_Carte = L.map('carteDiv').setView([45.469717, -73.563719], m_Zoom);

// Create click event handler
m_Carte.on('click', onMapClick);


// The function to create marker on click
var onMapClick = function (e) {
    var marqueur = L.marker([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng], {
                icon        : L.ExtraMarkers.icon({
                icon        : 'fa-number',
                prefix      : 'fa',
                markerColor : red,
                number      : 0
            })
        }).addTo(m_Carte).bindPopup(e.latlng.lat + ' ' + e.latlng.lng);
};
</script>
```